# Count unique objects in MongoDB (Java driver) in a memory efficient way

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to count the number of unique objects in a collection. My method involves getting a list of unique objects and calling .size() ... this causes memory issues when there are lots of objects. Do you know of a better way.

Here's what I am doing:

```
// note DBConfig.getMongoUrl() returns a String with the URL

public static int countUniqueProductsByKeyAndCode(String cKey, String cCode){
    List<Product> prods = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        MongoURI mongoURI = new MongoURI(DBConfig.getMongoUrl());
        DBCollection collection = mongoURI.connectDB().getCollection("Product");
        DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("cKey", cKey);
        query.put("cCode", cCode);
        prods = collection.distinct("name", query);
    } catch(Exception e){
      p.rint(e);
    }
    return prods.size();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation on 3.4 server.

```
public static int countUniqueProductsByKeyAndCode(String cKey, String cCode){
  int size = 0;
  try {
    MongoURI mongoURI = new MongoURI(DBConfig.getMongoUrl());
    DBCollection collection = mongoURI.connectDB().getCollection("Product");
    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("cKey", cKey);
    query.put("cCode", cCode);
    DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", query);
    DBObject id = new BasicDBObject("_id", "$name");
    DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", id);
    DBObject count = new BasicDBObject("$count", "count");
    AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match, group, count));
    size = (int) output.results().iterator().next().get("count");
   } catch(Exception e){
       p.rint(e);
   }
   return size;
}
```

For versions lower than 3.4 replace count with below group

```
 DBObject countd = new BasicDBObject("_id", null).append("count", new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1));
 DBObject count = new BasicDBObject("$group", countd);
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'll have to upgrade my MongoDB

Comment: Np. I've added the version complaint with older versions. Also update the mongodb java driver when you update mongodb server.

Comment: Hi the code is hanging when I test locally, I've upgraded the DB and library to 3.4 - the old code does work so it seems the upgrade was successful.

Comment: trying the code for the older version now (maybe something went wrong with the upgrade)

Comment: Will try a few different ways - perhaps it will work when pushed to the server.

Comment: I will test it locally too. Just to make sure it is sending the correct query to the server.

Comment: I've upgraded the DB and library to 3.6 (not sure if that is an issue) - now I get 0 for all test cases. Will keep trying.

Comment: here is the generated query `db.Product.aggregate([{ "$match" : { "cKey" : value, "cCode" : value2 } },
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "name" } },
{ "$count" : "count" }])` Try this from shell. I think I missed the $name. Let me fix it and you can try. **Updated** `db.Product.aggregate([{ "$match" : { "cKey" : value, "cCode" : value2 } },
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$name" } },
{ "$count" : "count" }])`

Comment: Did you figure out the problem ?